# How to handle type of users in HTML5

Tags: php, android, ios, html, cordova

I'm developing an app that access to a service and according to the user privileges make some stuff.

I've been searching a way to handle user permissions and I found that Kinvey provides something close to what I want, but I'm not so sure it will be enough.

I need a way how to handle the different user privileges using just HTML5 without compromising the user security. I'm not that experienced but think that just doing it with JS could bring me security problems in the future (you know, the source code can be seen in the browsers). So, I was considering to use PHP but the app will be moved later to iOS and Android with PhoneGap and I don't know If PHP will work fine in this environment.

I'm driving crazy, can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't do it in HTML5. You do it in PHP using the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html (any version) is a stateless protocol (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol), a simple communication layer that cannot provide anything like that.

What you are asking is simply impossible, it's like asking a paper envelope to remember your name.

Comment: Thanks in advance for the answer. I think I'll go for PHP web services and HTML5 for the phonegap part.